# How do I explicitly map policies in AuthServiceProvider using the Gate::guessPolicyNamesUsing(function ($modelClass) function?

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel can auto-discover policies as long as the model and policy follow standard Laravel naming conventions. Specifically, the policies must be in a Policies directory below the directory that contains the models. So, for example, the models may be placed in the app directory while the policies may be placed in the app/Policies directory.

However, I have my models in an "app/Models" folder, so, auto mapping is not working.

I have tried moving the policies folder into the Models folder, it didn't work.

I know the documentation says to use the guessPolicyNamesUsing function for explicit mapping, but I don't understand how to return the policy class.

Assuming I have an "App/Models/Post Model", with a corresponding PostPolicy in "App/Policies, how do I return policy class name in the guessPolicyNamesUsing function?

A brief code will help.

Thanks.